# liblinear one vs rest learn parameters

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, computer-vision

Liblinear (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) does not support for probability estimates.

Say I have three classes C1, C2 and C3. I want to learn the model paramters for each 'one vs rest' cases:

```
       C1 vs C2&C3, 
       c2 vs C1&C3 and
       C3 vs C1&C2
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

To make 'one-vs-rest' comparisons, simply relabel all the classes you're comparing against.  So in your first comparison, `C1` stays `C1` and `C2` and `C3` are grouped together as some new class like `C4`.

Comment: But then how can I compare the final results? (thats why I mentioned that liblinear does not support for probability estimates). I need the probability estimates to get the final classification results.

Comment: What classifier are you using in Liblinear?  I assume not an SVM else you would be using LibSVM, or might follow the Liblinear team's [directions](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/FAQ.html)

Comment: I am using SVM classification using libLinear. The problem is LibSVM supports probability estimates but libLinear does not support (supports probability estimates only for regression problems)

Comment: My advice would be either to use LibSVM or to look for implementations of [Lin's revision to Platt's solution](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/plattprob.pdf) or to follow the linked directions on the Liblinear website.