# Convert linear SVM answers to class probability?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, svm, isotonic

How to do this? I use SVMlight that returns me some scores (which say how sure SVM is that something belongs to a class?)

The questions is - can I do something to convert it to a % probability? Any formula, method that I could code for myself? Or is this impossible?

Comment: See also my comment [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51366/liblinear-one-vs-rest-learn-parameters/51372#comment100579_51372) for a literature reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

I guess you need a calibration procedure.

From Wikipedia

Calibration in classification is used to transform classifier scores into class membership probabilities.

I prefer Isotonic regression...

Answer (score 0):

The [LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) library has the option to train and output the associated probabilities.